# Which is the right way to insert a date in SQLite? When I inspect my database, the date isn't visible

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Which is the right way to insert a date in SQLite?

```
public boolean insertData(int data)
{  
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

     SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            cv.put("DATE", dateFormat.format(DATE));
     SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
            sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
}
```

Comment: What is issue in above code?

Comment: It’s batter you put in long format when you are reading read it at readable format

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded `Date` class and the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. In any case I think I’d go for saving [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: When i view my database date isn't visible. My further computation are using date as a factor and i'm new to this so please help!

Comment: I would say go with a long format. As you said everything was based on that date. If you want to represent it UI in a different format then you have to parse and convert it. It might be like a date format dependent.

Comment: @MJM Pls check edit.

Answer (score 0):

Inilialize sqlite database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
```

In onCreate() method use this.

```
Sqliteopenhelper helper = new Sqliteopenhelper(this);
db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

In the code.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

contentValues.put("DATE", dateFormat.format(DATE));

long rowNum = db.insert("TABLE_NAME", null, contentValues);
```

Use this proper way , I hope it will help for you...thanks

Answer (score 0):

the 3rd value in insert() have to be a [ContentValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html)!
look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite.html)